# How to remove all the dates where the value is not the max?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the dataframe where there are multiple values for each date but I just want the max Data_value for each date.
Note this data spans from 2005-2014.

```
        ID             Date    Element  Data_Value
49030   USC00207312 2005-01-01  TMAX    150
55424   USC00207308 2005-01-01  TMAX    150
18261   USC00205050 2005-01-01  TMAX    56
18049   USW00014853 2005-01-01  TMAX    56
60994   USW00004848 2005-01-01  TMAX    133
31715   USC00205451 2005-01-01  TMAX    156
```

Comment: df.groupby("Date").max() should be enough

Comment: If you need the row with the max Data_Value, use `df.loc[df.groupby("Date")["Data_Value"].idxmax()]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using groupby with idxmax and boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Date')['Data_Value'].idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
                 ID        Date Element  Data_Value
31715  USC00205451  2005-01-01    TMAX         156
```